# How to compare elements in two large XML files and choice where value is newer

Tags: php, xml, compare, nested-attributes, large-files

What is the best way to compare elements of two large XML files with products?

For example: If one XML file contains a `product` with the same `id` as in a second XML file, I'd like to select the product which has newer `date_added` and save it to new file.

Sample of my XML code:

```
<products>
    <product id="1" date_added="2016-05-05">
        <category><![CDATA[Category1]]></category>
        <name><![CDATA[Product name]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Description...]]></description>
        <attributes>
            <a name="Producent"><![CDATA[Producent]]></a>
            <a name="PN"><![CDATA[12345]]></a>
        </attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

For large XML files I would say that your best shot is to use the [SAX XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

It is a little complicated to manage if you compare it to SimpleXML, DOM parser or XMLReader but in terms of memory management I would say is what you are looking for.

Then, for your queries I would go for XPath and you can find nice clues here: [Is there any XPath processor for SAX model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863250/is-there-any-xpath-processor-for-sax-model)