# using SAX parser, how do you parse an xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Is it possible to give path expressions in SAX parser? I have an XML file which has a few same name tags, but they are in different element. Is there any way to differentiate between them. Here is the XML:

```
<report id="322077">
        <update>
          <when>1136117311</when>
          <what>nobody@mozilla.org</what>
        </update>
        <update>
          <when>1136117422</when>
          <what>asqueella@gmail.com</what>
        </update>
      </report>
    <report id="322074">
        <update>
          <when>1136117311</when>
          <what>nobody@mozilla.org</what>
        </update>
        <update>
          <when>1136117422</when>
          <what>asqueella@gmail.com</what>
        </update>
      </report>
    <report id="322076">
        <update>
          <when>1136117311</when>
          <what>nobody@mozilla.org</what>
        </update>
        <update>
          <when>1136117422</when>
          <what>asqueella@gmail.com</what>
        </update>
      </report>
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863250/is-there-any-xpath-processor-for-sax-model

Comment: Is it mandatory that you use a SAX parser? Navigating the structure is a lot easier if you read it into a DOM first. You then have lots of utility methods available to search and process nodes.

Comment: not  mandatory that you use a SAX parser. how can i do it with dom

Comment: SAX is a very low-level parsing interface, if you want to use it for its performance benefits then you are expected to track your position in the document "by hand". What are you actually trying to do with this file?

Answer (score 0):

```
String xml= // your xml
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
String expression="//update"; // See XPath
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ; 
    NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {
// Do what you want with that
```